# convert xml format into a formatted text file for metadata of Quickbird

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have a metadata of Quickbird in the format xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<isd>
    <IMD>
        <VERSION>AA</VERSION>
        <GENERATIONTIME>2008-01-04T18:36:17.000000Z</GENERATIONTIME>
        <PRODUCTORDERID>005708443040_01_P001</PRODUCTORDERID>
        <PRODUCTCATALOGID>901001001E9ED900</PRODUCTCATALOGID>
    </IMD>
</isd>
```

I would like to convert xml into text format as following:

> `version = "AA"; generationTime = 2008-01-04T18:36:17.000000Z; productOrderId = "005708443040_01_P001"; productCatalogId = "901001001E9ED900"; childCatalogId = "202001001E9ED800";`

I wrote the python code as following, but it didn't provide the result as I expected

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse("image.XML")
isd = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("isd")[0]
imds = isd.getElementsByTagName("IMD")
for imd in imds:
    print (imd)
```

Could you please help me how to do this task?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that your input is correct? It's not a well-formed XML file since it doesn't close the `<IMD>` tag, nor the `<isd>`. The semicolons separating the tags are not illegal, but they are quite unusual for XML files. Please edit your question and add a valid XML file.

Comment: Yes, it is a XML file, it close the <IMD> tad and <isd> tag.

Comment: One more question: is the last `print` in your actual Python code *indented*?

Comment: yes, the last print in my actual Python code is indented.

Comment: I posted an answer. It just doesn't convert to camel-case (the program would have to know somehow which letters to keep in uppercase, and it's not possible to deduce that from the tag names)

Answer (score 0):

This should print all the contents of the XML (It doesn't convert to camel-case as in your expected result because there's no way to know which characters to keep in uppercase and which to move to lowercase):

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse("image.XML")
isd = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("isd")[0]
imds = isd.getElementsByTagName("IMD")
for imd in imds:
   for child in imd.childNodes:
       if child.nodeType == minidom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE: 
            print child.nodeName+ ' = "' + child.childNodes[0].nodeValue + '"; ',
```

This will print:

> `VERSION = "AA"; GENERATIONTIME = "2008-01-04T18:36:17.000000Z"; PRODUCTORDERID = "005708443040_01_P001"; PRODUCTCATALOGID = "901001001E9ED900";`

See a working example in this **[Python Fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/minidom-python-example)** (click on "RUN" to see the result)

Comment: Thanks so much. Could I ask you more question: in IMD, I have the childnode <BAND_B>
  <ULLON>1.743666205900000e+02</ULLON>
  <BAND_B>. When I run as you suggested, the result is just BAND_B = "", while I would like the result is BEGIN_GROUP = BAND_BULLon =  174.36663827;

Comment: That would require an extra nested loop (or, if you had included that detail earlier when you first posted the example, a different strategy - the current one was OK for a simple file). Maybe you can deduce the solution from the current example.

Comment: Thanks so much. Could I ask you more question: in IMD, I have the childnode <BAND_B>
  <ULLON>1.743666205900000e+02</ULLON>
  <BAND_B>. When I run as you suggested, the result is just BAND_B = "", while I would like the result is BEGIN_GROUP = BAND_B  ULLon =  174.36663827 END_GROUP = BAND_B. Could you please help me? I am sorry since it is the first time I wrote the code so I asked a lot.

Comment: Yes, I will try to write based on the current example.

Comment: I think you should ask a new question, since there are so many new details. With a more complex file, I would use a different strategy, such as XSLT (using libxslt, or xsltproc or Saxon, etc.). I see you are new to StackOverflow. I suggest you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, use the editor correctly (it helps you format the code), include well-formed code and describe your problem the best you can. That will help you not only get better answers, but also avoid downvotes.

Comment: It's OK to ask for small follow-up questions in the comments. But if you want something very different (or when you start adding code in the comments) perhaps you should write a new question. Finally, when an answer solves the problem you asked in the question, you should mark it as the accepted answer, and also upvote it if you think it was helpful.